# No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule' after reinstalling node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular5

I was having some problems with some node dependencies, so I deleted the whole node_modules folder, after that running `ng serve` will lead to the mentioned error

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavComponent } from './shared/nav/nav.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './shared/footer/footer.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavComponent,
    FooterComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And my main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';
import { environment } from './environments/environment';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please go through this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8798).

The issue is fixed only when manually re installed angular/cli. The webpack should come as a part of @angular/cli.

```
npm remove webpack
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

.
This should fix your issue.
If this didn't, clear the whole node_modules folder
then

```
npm cache clean --force
npm install
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

If @angular/cli install fails
Retry `npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest` again.

Comment: Tried the whole process, all I get is `18% building modules 72/79 modules 7 active ...ode_modules/webpack/buildin/module.js` it will stay frozen

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error because of a typo in `loadChildren` when trying to lazy load a module.